# declared vs undeclared variables in a js function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, constructor

In the following piece of code (short version of a function taken from "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja") I don't understand the behaviour of  the 'initializing' variable when it's declared as opposed to when it's not declared.

If I declare it then it's value is always going to be false. Another thing I noticed is, that the way in which the variable is declared is relevant only when proto = new this(), if proto = new Class() the 'initialize' variable has a predictable behaviour. Can somebody be so kind as to explain me the dynamics of such a behaviour ?

```js
Object.subClass = function(properties) {

  initializing = true;
  var proto = new this();
  initializing = false;

  function Class() {
    console.log(initializing)
  }

  Class.prototype = proto;
  Class.constructor = Class;
  Class.subClass = arguments.callee;
  return Class;
};

var Constructor = Object.subClass()
var subConstructor = Constructor.subClass() // true
var instance = new subConstructor() // false

// if var  initializing = true;
var proto = new this();
initializing = false;

var Constructor = Object.subClass()
var subConstructor = Constructor.subClass() // false
var instance = new subConstructor() // false
```

Comment: FYI, this example is full of things you should not do in JavaScript. It's the wrong way to implement inheritance.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. You've talked about `initializing` always being `false` if you declare it, which is incorrect (running the code above with the `var` declaration uncommented [and the "if" removed from in front of it] still logs `true` then `false`). The snippet also throws an error. Update the question with exactly the code (both with and without the declaration) that demonstrates what you're asking about.

Comment: And as Madara said, this is just a seriously-flawed way to implement inheritance. It calls the superclass constructor at the wrong time, with no arguments. Apparently this is what the `initializing` flag is trying to correct, but it's just flatly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, my bad for not making myself clear enough. Here is another try:

```
 Object.subClass = function(properties) {

    initializing = true;
    var proto = new this();
    initializing = false;

    function Class() {
        console.log(initializing)
    }

    Class.prototype = proto;
    Class.constructor = Class;
    Class.subClass = arguments.callee;
    return Class;
};

 var Constructor = Object.subClass()
 var subConstructor = Constructor.subClass() // true
 var instance = new subConstructor() // false

 Object.subClass = function(properties) {

   var initializing = true;
   var proto = new this();
       initializing = false;

    function Class() {
        console.log(initializing)
    }

    Class.prototype = proto;
    Class.constructor = Class;
    Class.subClass = arguments.callee;
    return Class;
};

 var Constructor = Object.subClass()
 var subConstructor = Constructor.subClass() // false
 var instance = new subConstructor() // false
```

I know this is a bad way to implement prototype-based programming, my question stems from the behaviour of the initialize variable.

As you can observe in the first example of Object.subClass, the undeclared 'initializing' variable, when invoked, returns true or false depending on the context in which is invoked

In the second example of Object.subClass, the declared 'initializing' variable, when invoked, returns only false, regardless of the context in which is invoked.